# Need a way to hide marker on apex charts when y-axis has 0 value

Tags: apexcharts

I need a way to hide marker on apex charts when the y-axis has 0 value.
For instance, this is my dataset,

```
d = [{x:1, y:0}, {x:2, y:10}]
```

So, when my chart renders, I should see one marker with point (2,10) on the chart.

If this makes sense, then can you please help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set marker's size dynamically based on y-value, but you can use the `markers.discrete` option.

```js
markers: {
  size: 6,
  discrete: [
    {
      seriesIndex: 0,
      dataPointIndex: 0,
      size: 0
    },
    {
      seriesIndex: 0,
      dataPointIndex: 1,
      fillColor: '#419EF7',
      strokeColor: '#fff',
      size: 6
    }
  ]
}
```

[Docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/markers/#markerDiscrete)