# Apexcharts how to remove markers and labels and just show the line

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

[image]

I have this chart. I feel those labels on the chart bring no value and distract us from seeing the actual curves. How to I remove those numbers on top of the lines?

This is my actual code, (The bit that says "markers" seems to make no difference at all).

```
<ReactApexChart options={{
          chart: {
            height: 350,
            type: 'area'
          },
          tooltip: {
            
            x: {
              formatter: function (seriesName) {
                let ano = Math.floor(seriesName/12);
                let mes = seriesName%12;
                return "Pagamento: " + seriesName + " - ano " + ano + " mês " + mes
              },
            },
          },
          markers: { size: 0,
            colors: undefined,
            strokeColors: '#fff',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            strokeOpacity: 0.9,
            strokeDashArray: 0,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            discrete: [],
            shape: "circle",
            radius: 2,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
            onClick: undefined,
            onDblClick: undefined,
            showNullDataPoints: true,
            hover: {
              size: undefined,
              sizeOffset: 3
            }},
          xaxis: {
            type: 'numeric',
            categories: categories}
          }} series={[{
            name: 'Sem Amortização',
            data: beforeSeries
          }, {
            name: 'Com Amortização',
            data: afterSeries,
          }]} type="area" height={350} />
```

Edit: I thought those numbers where special markers, turns out they are labels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a way to hide marker on apex charts when y-axis has 0 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532585/need-a-way-to-hide-marker-on-apex-charts-when-y-axis-has-0-value), https://stackoverflow.com/a/64912532/5324829

Comment: it did, I needed to disable labels not markers.

Comment: Then update your Question like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable [`dataLabels`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/).

Here is a very basic area chart without them:

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data: [10, 20, 15]
  }],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'area'
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false // <--- HERE
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3']
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```